# RESTful API for backup and restore

Tags: rest, api-design, hateoas

I'm about to design a RESTful API for backing up and restoring a database.

And I wonder if there is an approach that is RESTful as well as reasonable...

The API should support 3 operations:

1. Make a backup.
2. List available backups (mainly for the purpose of selecting one for restore).
3. Restore from a particular backup.

The first two look pretty straightforward:

```
paths:
  /foo/backups:
    post:
      # create a backup
  /foo/backups:
    get:
      # list available backups
```

But what about restoring from a backup?

I see some options - none of them really satisfying me so far:

1. Forget REST and go for RPC over HTTP., Just something like

   ```
   paths:
     /foo/backups/{backupId}:
       post:
         requestBody:
           content:
             application/json:
               schema:
                 object:
                   properties:
                     action: { type: string }
               examples:
                 theBody:
                   value:
                     action: restore
   ```
2. GET request for a particular backup (`/foo/backups/{backupId}`):

   ```
   paths:
     /foo/backups/{backupId}:
       get:
         # restore the database from this backup
   ```

   From REST perspective this might be fine for the following reasons:

   - The resource (`/foo/backups/{backupId}`) won't be amended.
   - The operation is idempotent

   But there is a very strong side-effect (restoring the database) that I find completely counterintuitive for a GET request.
3. POST (or PUT or PATCH) request for a particular backup (`/foo/backups/{backupId}`):

   In the simplest case we wouldn't post anything. In other cases we might post a restore-comment or similar.

   ```
   paths:
     /foo/backups/{backupId}:
       post:
         # restore the database from this backup
   ```

   In neither case it looks right to post nothing or a comment to a backup for triggering a restore.
4. Introduce a `restores` resource to operate on: In this case `/foo/restores/{backupId}` would represent a collection of executed DB restores (e.g. with timestamp and comment)

   ```
   paths:
     /foo/restores/{backupId}:
       post:
         description: Adds a restore record to this restore collection
         requestBody:
           content:
             application/json:
               schema:
                 object:
                   properties:
                     comment: { type: string }
               examples:
                 theBody:
                   value:
                     comment: Restored because of DB corruption after power failure.
   ```

   Looks more reasonable and RESTful but it doesn't really convice me.
5. Provide a PATCH operation on `/foo/backups/{backupId}` that creates a new resource - e.g. `/foo/backups/{backupId}/restores/{restoreId}`

   ```
   paths:
     /foo/backups/{backupId}:
       patch:
         description: Adds a restore record to the restores collection of this backup
         requestBody:
           content:
             application/json:
               schema:
                 object:
                   properties:
                     action: { type: string }
                     comment: { type: string }
               examples:
                 theBody:
                   value:
                     action: restore
                     comment: Restored because of DB corruption after power failure.
   ```

   To me this looks like a quite reasonable approach so far but it looks quite RPC-like rather than RESTful.

Are there

- ideas for better approaches
- arguments why one of those I suggested is better than the others
- any missing aspects that should be considered?

Comment: Don't worry aobut deleting, it's not important. I restored your question because it's still useful as a record.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of your options are viable - remember, there isn't a one size fits all solution.

Personally, I believe **option 4**, with a little change, would be ideal. Might be a little biased, but that's how I've used it in the past.

The endpoint can look like this:

```
POST /foo/restores
```

The request body will include the `backup_id`.

Therefore:

`GET /foo/restores` - returns all restore records.

`GET /fee/restores/{restore_id}` - returns specific restore record.

I think it's ideal because restoration (i.e. recovery) and backup are two distinct actions with their own properties, and it's a good idea not to embed them within each other. Having two different resources achieves that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that backup and restore are distinct operations with their own properties. But they're not independent. Restores definitely depend on backups - no restore without backup. That's why option 4 didn't convince me.